# Is it possible to get all the domain names assigned to an IP address?

Tags: ip, domain-name

Is it possible to get all the domain names assigned to an IP address?

Comment: I know this has been asked more than once already but I can't for the life of me find any of the others.

Comment: It's not a "direct" solution, but there are companies out there that aggregate network information.  ServerSniff.net has a tool that will list all of the domains they know of that direct to a given IP address.  It's not 100% accurate or fail-safe, but it's a good place to start.  http://www.serversniff.net/content.php?do=hostonip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not generally. The DNS system was not designed for this kind of one-to-many search, just many-to-one. It may be specifically possible if you know all the domains are hosted by a single DNS provider, and even then it may not be doable.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what sysadmin1138 has said, there are really only two possible ways to do this.

1. Do a forward lookup on every possible domain name, including all possible subdomains if that is relevant to you.
2. Do a reverse lookup on the IP address.

Number 1 is clearly impossible due to the number of lookups needed, plus much of the data would probably be invalid before you get even a few percent into the list.

Number 2 may work in some cases but in general not every forward lookup has a corresponding reverse lookup, which means you cannot get the complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bing](http://bing.com) with the query "IP:69.59.196.211". For [example](http://www.bing.com/search?q=IP%3A69.59.196.211&go=&form=QBRE&qs=n&sk=).

Comment: I know but I was looking for direct independent solution.

Comment: Wrong. Despite appearances, that will NOT achieve the desired results. As a check I just tried it using an IP address under my control that has 5 domains and Bing return zero results. There are no reverse lookups configured for any of those domains, so there's no way to look them up.

Comment: Looks like this feature was removed anyhow.